# Fixing Data in Large Dataframes

Tags: python, pandas, join, fuzzy-search

I have two dataframes that I'm joining on `ID`. `df1` contains neatly-formatted names:

```
          ID Company Symbol
0  68243Q106  AA Inc     AA
1  336901103  BB Inc     BB
2  100564000  CC Inc     CC
```

And `df2` is created by scraping data from a website and joining on `ID`.

But sometimes the `ID`s are 1) entered incorrectly on the site (e.g., missing a digit), or 2) new `ID`s that don't yet exist in `df1`.

```
  Investor      Date         ID Company Symbol
0     Pete   9/30/13   68243Q10  aa inc    NaN
1     Mike  12/31/16  68243Q106  AA Inc     AA
2     Pete   3/31/19  68243Q106  AA Inc     AA
3     Pete   6/30/15   36901103  bb inc    NaN
4     Pete   3/31/17  336901103  BB Inc     BB
5     Mike   6/30/17  336901103  BB Inc     BB
6     Pete   6/30/17  100564000  CC Inc     CC
7     Mike   6/30/16  1O056400O     NaN    NaN
8     Pete   6/30/17    1111111     New    NaN
```

- row `0`, the `ID` is missing the trailing `6` (`68243Q10` vs `68243Q106`)
- row `3`, the `ID` is missing the leading `3` (`36901103` vs `336901103`)
- row `7`, the `ID` contains some "O's" instead of zeroes (`1O056400O` vs `100564000`)
- row 8, the ID is new

I'm curious how people would approach this problem. I've looked at fuzzy match, and while it works pretty well, it also returns too many false positives in the cases where it is a truly new ID. So while that approach "fixes" this problem, it creates an equally-challenging new problem at the same time.

Comment: you simply have to adopt a criterion, and then see how you can code it. But that first problem is not a coding problem

Comment: Not sure I follow. Can you elaborate?

Comment: I mean, it's hard to code something you don't know. First you have to try to establish criteria. By then encode them

Comment: Right so part of the problem is I don't know where the errors are and it's hard finding them all in a dataframe with 1.5m rows. It's easier in something like Excel where I can sort, filter, and scroll through a bunch of data. But I can't use Excel as it misformats and alters some of the data. So any other recommendations on how to discover and fix errors like this?